# Windsor Castle: good sources for documentation, tutorials

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I'm trying to assemble a list of good documentation sources for Windsor Castle (apart from analyzing its source code). I'm especially interested in documentation about the fluent configuration API. Here's what I've found myself:

- [BitterCoder's Wiki Container Tutorials](http://wiki.bittercoder.com/Default.aspx?Page=ContainerTutorials&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
- [DimeCast's Setting up Castle Windsor for Auto Registration](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/CastFeedDetails/60)
- http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Home
- [Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection with Castle Windsor Container](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart1.aspx)

Feel free to add more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a yahoo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/mausch/castle) I built that aggregates Castle-related blog posts. Now readable via http://www.castleproject.org/community/blogs.aspx

[Castleproject.org](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/index.html) has lots of info about the xml config and internals

Answer (score 2):

Mike Hadlow as some good stuff on castle windsor including multi-tenancy stuff

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/

Colin G